# Get actionbar displayoptions on orientation change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, orientation-changes

I'm trying to save the actionbar display options, so when orientation changes, I can get back its value.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(savedInstanceState.getInt("ab_displayoptions"));
    }
// ...
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("ab_displayoptions", actionBar.getDisplayOptions());
}
```

But when I try to get the value in onCreateView(), I get this:

```
Must be one or more of: ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME, ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
```

Any other better way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

getDisplayOptions returns an int, not a long. Furthermore do some checking if it's even set. Try this:

Fetch state:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    int opts = savedInstanceState.getInt("ab_displayoptions", -1);
    if (opts != -1) {
        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(opts);
    }
}
```

Save state:

```
outState.putInt("ab_displayoptions", actionBar.getDisplayOptions());
```